# Character missing when use the InputStreamReader class in Java

Tags: java, string, input, io, stream

I had written some codes to read from a text file char by char and then print it to the screen,but the result had made me feel confused,here it is:

this is the code that i had written

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
public class learnIO
{


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

                var in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("test1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                while(in.read() != -1){

                        System.out.println((char)in.read());
                }


        }


}
```

the content and encoding scheme of the file:

> file test1.txt
>
> test1.txt: ASCII text
>
> cat test1.txt
>
> hello, world!

the result is:

> e
>
> l
>
> ,
>
> w
>
> r
>
> d

some char had missed，Why did this happen？

Comment: You do a while (in.read() != -1). This reads and discards a character. I'd also use a BufferedReader instead of an InputStreamReader.

Answer (score 0):

return type of read method of InputStreamReader is int that takes 4 bytes
and char type is 2 bytes so casting int to char you skip 2 bytes

refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use InputStreamReader inside BufferedReader as from the official oracle documentation it says that

> An InputStreamReader is a bridge from byte streams to character streams: It reads bytes and decodes them into characters using a specified charset. The charset that it uses may be specified by name or maybe given explicitly, or the platform's default charset may be accepted.
>
> Each invocation of one of an InputStreamReader's read() methods may cause one or more bytes to be read from the underlying byte-input stream.
>
> To enable the efficient conversion of bytes to characters, more bytes may be read ahead from the underlying stream than are necessary to satisfy the current read operation.
>
> For top efficiency, consider wrapping an InputStreamReader within a BufferedReader. For example:
>
> BufferedReader in
>      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

So the solution to your problem can be solved using the following code

```
 try {
                // Open the file that is the first
                // command line parameter
                FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("hello.txt");
                // Get the object of DataInputStream
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                //Read File Line By Line
                char c;
                while ((c = (char) br.read()) != (char) -1) {
                    // Print the content on the console
                    String character = Character.toString(c);
                    System.out.println(character);
                }
                //Close the input stream
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
```